# Protect ClickOnce application hosting on AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, clickonce

My WPF application was published using ClickOnce. It can be updated automatically as I hosted it on a AWS S3 bucket. The problem I am facing is that everyone can access the files and folders of the app because they are public (in order for the app to read the dependencies). Is there a way to prevent people from accessing the app's files/folders but only the app?